# Check box functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues in coding the functionality that my client needed.
The request is as below.

There will be 5 checkboxes and if we select 1 & 2 - 3rd checkbox need to be selected automatically and if only 4th selected then 5th checkbox need to be checked.

```js
(e=>{e.validator.addMethod("emailtld",function(e,t){return/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(e)},"Please enter a valid email address in the format: yourname@example.com");let t=e("#reg");if(!t)return!1;function n(t){return""!=e(t).attr("data-group")?e('[data-group-item="'+e(t).attr("data-group")+'"]'):null}function r(t){return""!=e(t).attr("data-group-item")?e('[data-group="'+e(t).attr("data-group-item")+'"]'):null}function a(t){return""!=e(t).attr("data-group-item")?e('[data-group-item="'+e(t).attr("data-group-item")+'"]'):null}function u(t){let r=n(t);if(e(t).prop("checked",!1),null==r)return!1;r.each(function(e,t){u(t)})}function o(t){let n=r(t);if(e(t).prop("checked",!1),null==n)return!1;n.each(function(e,t){o(t)})}function i(t){let r=n(t);if(e(t).prop("checked",!0),null==r)return!1;r.each(function(e,t){i(t)})}function c(t){let n=a(t),r=e(n).length==e(n).filter(":checked").length;r&&l(t)}function l(t){let n=r(t);n&&(e(n).prop("checked",!0),n.each(function(e,t){c(t)}))}t.validate({normalizer:function(t){return e.trim(t)},errorElement:"p",errorClass:"has-error",validClass:"is-valid",onfocusout:function(t){e(t).valid()},errorPlacement:function(e,t){t.is(":checkbox")?e.insertBefore('input[type="submit"]'):e.insertAfter(t)},rules:{"channel[]":{required:!0}},messages:{"channel[]":{required:"Please select at least one channel to unsubscribe from"}}}),e("[data-group]").on("change",function(){let t=e(this),n=t.is(":checked");n?i(t):(u(t),o(t))}),e('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change",t=>e(t.target).trigger("focusout"))})($);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<p class="m-input-label">Nurtec&nbsp;ODT home office emails</p>
<div class="m-checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="HCP_Nurtec_HomeOfficeAnnouncement_Emails" name="channel[]" data-group="" data-group-item="allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails" class="m-input-hidden"> 
    <label for="HCP_Nurtec_HomeOfficeAnnouncement_Emails">All Nurtec ODT announcement emails</label>
</div>
<div class="m-checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="HCP_Nurtec_HomeOfficeClinicalEducational_Emails" name="channel[]" data-group="" data-group-item="allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails" class="m-input-hidden"> 
    <label for="HCP_Nurtec_HomeOfficeClinicalEducational_Emails">All Nurtec ODT clinical and educational emails</label>
</div>
<div class="m-checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails" name="channel[]" data-group="allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails" data-group-item="allBiohaven" class="m-input-hidden"> 
    <label for="allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails">All Nurtec ODT home office emails</label>
</div>

            <hr class="m-hr" />

            <p class="m-input-label">Nurtec&nbsp;ODT rep-delivered emails</p>
<div class="m-checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="HCP_Nurtec_RepDelivered_Emails" name="channel[]" data-group="" data-group-item="allBiohaven" class="m-input-hidden"> 
    <label for="HCP_Nurtec_RepDelivered_Emails">All Nurtec ODT rep-delivered emails</label>
</div>

            <hr class="m-hr" />
<div class="m-checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="allBiohaven" name="channel[]" data-group="allBiohaven" data-group-item="" class="m-input-hidden"> 
    <label for="allBiohaven">All Nurtec ODT emails</label>
</div>

        <button type="submit" class="m-button">unsubscribe</button>
```

Comment: Sound like a good use case for a [delegated](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). Something like `yourForm.addEventListener("input", ({ target }) => { if(target === document.getElementById("allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails")){ return; } document.getElementById("allNurtecHomeOfficeEmails").checked = document.getElementById("HCP_Nurtec_HomeOfficeAnnouncement_Emails").checked && document.getElementById("HCP_Nurtec_HomeOfficeClinicalEducational_Emails").checked; })`…

Comment: You have to try Jquery for this purpose.

Comment: Hi @SebastianSimon - Added my HTML and Javascript to the snippet. Could you please look at it and help in solving this?

Comment: @IrshadKhan-i'm looking for a solution and happy to go with either of them.

Comment: The current script which I had is working in a opposite direction and not sure what need to fixed